# How to use multiple viewmodels in single fragment in Android?

Tags: android-fragments, viewmodel, autocompletetextview, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

Let's say I have DashboadFragment which has its own `ViewModel` named `DashboadViewModel`. I have created separate layout for `AutoCompleteTextView` which is included in `fragment_dashboard.xml` file. I have created separate `ViewModel` for `AutoCompleteTextView` which is `AutoCompleteTextViewViewModel`. So here I have tried to observe the data which are typing in `AutoCompleteTextView` into `DashboardFragment` but it didn't worked.

I have recently started development in MVVM Pattern.

Comment: In your scenario please do not create view models of such atomicity - just operate with hosting fragment's view model.

Comment: Yes but actually, its common layout and used in whole application. So I have to create common ViewModel so it can be usable with other fragment's ViewModel.

Comment: It makes sense for composability, as is your use-case. Let's not forget that a ViewModel is just a headless Fragment working to help neaten code and make business logic probable for testing. A ViewModel with the same lifecycle could theoretically hold reference to another with the exact same lifecycle without any problem (though I'd avoid tight-coupling like that). Please provide more code regarding your specific problem, it can work it just depends how you went about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between Fragment using the delegate viewModels

```
private val viewModel: ListViewModel by viewModels({requireParentFragment()})
```

it does mean that you will have in your dashboardFragment a AutoCompleteTextViewViewModel.

Another solution will be to use the `setFragmentResult()`API

See https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#share_data_between_a_parent_and_child_fragment
and https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result for more informations